# Trying to include url patterns in urls folder of django project

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls

I'm working on a django project where I was putting all of the url patterns into one urlConf of the app for my project. I decided to break them up and just include them in the root project's url file. The root URLConf is in cms/urls.py while the ones I am trying to include is located at cms/coltrane/urls I have my models imported in each of the seperate url files in that folder like so

```
from coltrane.models import Entry
```

I don't know if it matters but for some reason pyCharm is saying that coltrane is an unresolved reference I don't know if that is affecting it or not. I included them in the root like so

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from coltrane.models import Entry

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^heart/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^heart/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^weblog/', include('coltrane.urls.entries')),
    url(r'^weblog/categories/', include('coltrane.urls.categories')),
    url(r'^weblog/links/', include('coltrane.urls.links')),
    url(r'^weblog/tags/', include('coltrane.urls.entries')),
url(r'^search/$', 'cms.search.views.search'),
#url(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
)
```

I'm using a virtualenv to develop this as well. When I run the dev server I can load and get the error stating that,

> TemplateSyntaxError at /heart/
>   Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: The included urlconf coltrane.urls doesn't have >any patterns in it

I'm at a lose as what could be causing it or why it is not recogonizing the urls folder I have a blank `__init__.py` file to ensure django notices it but it still won't.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a typo in your answer but `init.py` should be `__init__.py`

Comment: Yeah it's a typo. The more I think about it I think it has something to do with the whole unresolved reference part but I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's may be for the fact that you have **urls.py** and a directory named **urls** in the same package. You cannot have them both with the same name. You need to change either of them or you can copy the contents of **urls.py** into **urls/__init__.py** and delete **urls.py**

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the folder urls as this conflicts with the file urls.py. change the folder to app_urls or something similar and this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

I don think the include should start with an 'url'?